# Start Laravel 5.3 project

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I'm having this error when I type: php artisan serve

```
> Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/ Error in
> command line: unrecognised option '-S' Usage:
> 
>    /usr/bin/hhvm [-m <mode>] [<options>] [<arg1>] [<arg2>] ...
```

But when I start a Laravel project 4.2 I don't have this error. 
Tanks for your help.

Comment: Is this PHP or HHVM? What version?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following and re-run the php artisan server command:

- update your composer by running : composer update in the terminal.
- give write permission to storage, vendor, and views folder
- generate a new key : php artisan key:generate